# Any way to test if an action exists based on a URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

My login page has a redirectURL associated with it, but the redirectURL isn't always valid, for example if the user is logged out and then clicks a button to POST to a url that has no associated GET method, or if RedirectToAction is used.

I have tried many methods of seeing if a route is valid prior to redirecting there, but none have worked.

My returnURL is `/MyApplicationName/SomeController/SomeAction/12345`

I have tried:

`ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, returnUrl, null);`

`BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(returnUrl, false)`

and some stuff I found on SO about RouteData.

Nothing has worked so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is quite a bit involved (including .NET Reflection) to do this. Have a look at the source code of [MvcRouteTester](https://github.com/AnthonySteele/MvcRouteTester) and the [AuthorizeAttributeAclModule](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Security/AuthorizeAttributeAclModule.cs#L85) of `MvcSiteMapProvider`.

Comment: did you find a solution on your own?

Comment: I haven't solved this yet, bug still sitting in bugtracker! I might just manually program in some redirection keyvaluepairs for all the post ones and check them before I redirect. If I have time I will try to extract the controller and action and do some reflection to examine a controller and see if it has a valid method for the URL, if I can read the attributes. We'll see. If I solve it that way I will post an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following,

```
if (Request.Url != null)
{
    var request = new HttpRequest(null, Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + givenUrl, string.Empty);
    var response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
    var httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);
    var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));

    if (routeData != null)
    {
        var values = routeData.Values;
        var controllerName = values["controller"].ToString();
        var actionName = values["action"].ToString();

        var controllerType =
            (from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from t in a.GetTypes()
            where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                  string.Equals(controllerName + "Controller", t.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            select t).FirstOrDefault();
        if (new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType).GetCanonicalActions()
                                                             .Any(x => x.ActionName == actionName))
        {
            //Action Exists
        }

    }
}
```

here,

1. a request and response is created for a httpcontext to test for the
   controller and action.
2. routedata are collected with the httpcontext.
3. find the controller type with reflection.
4. find the action names from the controller type and tested if the
   actionname in routedata exists in the action name collection from
   the controller.

hope this helps.

Comment: That looks good, I just need to figure out how to filter it to GET actions only, because POST actions won't work with a redirect

Comment: Your code works great! To finish it off, I loop through all actions instead of using `.Any` (because there may be a GET and POST with the same name), I then cast the `ActionDescriptor` to a `ReflectedActionDescriptor` which has a `MethodInfo` property. Then I can do `reflectedAction.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ActionMethodSelectorAttribute), true).Cast<ActionMethodSelectorAttribute>().ToList();` which will give me all attributes. If there are any attributes that are type of 'HttpPostAttribute' then it is a POST, otherwise it's a GET.